# Выполняется действие кнопки без нажатия на неё

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Почему-то при генерации окна сразу выполняется действие кнопки (в моём случае создаётся новое окно с листбоксом). В дальнейшем нажатие на кнопку ничего не выполняет. Вот часть кода:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
class MyButton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, text="", height = 35, width = 35, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, height=height, width=width)
        
        self.pack_propagate(0)
        self._btn = Button(self, text = text, *args, **kwargs)
        self._btn.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
def cmnd(i) :
    a = Toplevel(root)
    n = nmbr[i]
    l = Listbox(a, selectmode=SINGLE, width=15, height=10)
    l.pack()
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("")
 
        i = 0
        b0 = MyButton(self, text= butt_txt(i), style = butt_stl(i), command = cmnd(i))
        b0.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: `= cmnd(i)` - сами же вызываете команду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сразу ее выполняете () значит вызов

Измените это
`command = cmnd(i))`
На это `command=lambda: cmnd(i))`

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало.

Comment: @Toha, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, поставьте зеленую галочку слева и проголосуйте за него. А комментарии не для этого.

Comment: @Глеб, И всё равно не понял, почему? во всех талмудах "command =" - это действие, которое выполняется при срабатывании кнопки.... На какой подводный камень наступил? P.S. с listbox похожая проблема. l.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', limiting(i, l.get(l.curselection()), nmbr)) срабатывает до выбора и лямбда не помогает.  Что почитать, чтоб понять?

Comment: Право же, я  начинающий самоучка, посему многого не знаю. От того не понимаю, почему в общем command = cmnd(i)) работает, а у меня только через лямбду....  в общем  l.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', limiting(i, l.get(l.curselection()), nmbr)) работает, а у меня нет...  а если  l.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda: limiting(i, l.get(l.curselection()), nmbr)), то ошибка - лябда принимает 0 аргументов, а дают 1

Comment: Тогда пиши lambda arg: limiting(i, l.get(l.curselection()), nmbr))